# Why is this async Jasmine test failing?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

Why is this test failing, saying that the `onSuccess` spy was never called?

```
it('should correctly call the success callback',function(done)
{
    const callbacks={
        onSuccess:function()
        {
            console.log('OK');
            done();
        },
        onError:function()
        {
            console.log('ERR');
            done();
        }
    };

    spyOn(callbacks,'onSuccess').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(callbacks,'onError').and.callThrough();

    doSomethingAsync(callbacks.onSuccess,callbacks.onError);

    expect(callbacks.onSuccess).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(callbacks.onError).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

When running the test, I get an error saying `Expected spy onSuccess to have been called.`.
Right above that, there's a console log saying "OK", meaning that the spy was called and that it called through.

Comment: The `expect()` calls are called _before_ `doSomethingAsync()` has finished, so you need to somehow wait for it to finish.

Comment: Hm, doesn't it wait for `done()` to be called before assessing expectations?

Comment: No, calling `done` signals that the test (including any assertions) has finished.

Comment: You should post that as answer since it's why they fail. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to assert that one callback is called and another one isn't without stubbing `doSomethingAsync` or its internals.

Here's a contrived edge case:

```
function doSomethingAsync(onSuccess, onError) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    onSuccess('hello');
  }, 500);
  setTimeout(function() {
    onError(new Error('foo'));
  }, 1000);
}
```

(so it calls `onSuccess` after half a second, and `onError` after a second)

If you assert, in the `onSuccess` handler, that `onError` hasn't been called, the test will pass, even though `onError` *is* getting called (albeit half a second later).

This is something that you cannot easily work around, unless (as stated before) you stub (the internals of) `doSomethingAsync`.

If you simply want to test if `doSomethingAsync` calls the right handler, you can shorten your test case to this (provided that it's not strictly necessary to call the handlers in your `callbacks` object):

```
it('should correctly call the success callback',function(done) {
  doSomethingAsync(done, done.fail);
});
```

(this doesn't catch `doSomethingAsync` calling *both* handlers, though; if it calls `onSuccess` before `onError`, the test will pass).

Comment: Thank you. [extra chars]

Comment: I think I'm missing some thing here but your answer is talking about stubbing out the subject of the test. If your testing doSomethingAsync and you stub out that function what are you testing other than the stub?

Comment: @Stewart yeah, the wording isn't great. What I meant is that, taking my contrived example, it may be necessary to stub out `setTimeout` to test the workings of `doSomeThingAsync`. Stubbing `doSomethingAsync` entirely might be necessary if you're testing some _other_ function that relies on it.